# add new table row with html and <div class="input-group-addon">€</div> with javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this code and i cant see the `<div class="input-group-addon">€</div>` visual effect

```
$(document).on('click', '#addRows', function() { 
    count++;
    var html = '';
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_'+count+'" style="text-align:right" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_'+count+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_'+count+'" style="text-align:right" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td><div class="input-group-addon">€</div>';
    html += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+count+'" style="text-align:right" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_'+count+'" style="text-align:right" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>'+'<div class="input-group-addon">€</div>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('#invoiceItem').append(html);
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHlGg.png)

Comment: If that isn’t working simplify things (remove inline JavaScript, remove all the attributes, use a style sheet or move styles to the head of the document...) and add complexity once it’s working at its simplest. If, at its simplest (adding only empty `<td>` elements for example) it’s not working ask us about that, but read the “*[mcve]*” and “*[ask]*” guidance first.

Comment: Your `div`s are outside of the table elements, which is invalid. The only valid children of `<tr>` are `<td>` and `<th>`.

Comment: Use the correct elements and it'll work: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#basic-example (i.e. an input-group div wrapping the input and an input-group-append div)

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, my div was outside of a <td>, the problem is solved! thanks

Comment: @ChrisG after enter the div inside the <th> (@HereticMonkey) ,  i used an input-group div wrapping the input and the output was perfect ! thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your div is outside of a `<td>` and therefore outside of the table.  Did you want it outside of the table?  If so I would reorganize your code either so you put in the table and then put in the div and arrange using grid or floats,

OR

you put it in another cell in the table, that is wrapped in `<td><div>...</div></td>`

Also, make sure you initialize the count and include jquery.